# Correct way to find element "by.id()" with nested components and bound [id] fields

Tags: angular, protractor

I made a GitHub issue on the angular/protractor site but I was told that I should ask the question here since it wasn't a bug (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5118#issuecomment-453169976)

I currently have an example on stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/protractor-bug-example)

My question is why does `element(by.id('123-789'))` work in my example when the [id] is being set in the `app.component.ts` but whenever it is nested inside another component, why does it return an error and trying to find the id with `By(css selector, *[id="\31 23-456-789"])`

Comment: Have you tried it as an xpath? If so what were those results like?  Does using double quotes change anything such as : element(by.id(:123-789")) .

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be an issue with Selenium WebdriverJS trying to identify elements by id that start with a digit. I'm not sure how you are able to interact with the first element at all.

I tested this out and saw the following:

```
element(by.id('14a')) -> becomes [id="\31 4a"]
element(by.id('a')) -> becomes [id="a"]
element(by.id('a14')) -> becomes [id="a14"]
```

May be worth sharing you webdriver version also.